# Какие существуют ограничения на размер текста в ответе?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, ответы

Или какое максимальное количество символов может быть в ответе?

Comment: 30к символов...(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PWkD.jpg)

Comment: А я в поиске искал по "ограничение размера текста", "ограничение текста", "большой ответ", "ограничение размера ответа" так и не нашёл, даже через гугл, я пытался) Спасибо. А чего ответом не сделали?

Comment: Я слишком стеснительный

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, соберись, тряпка, и пиши ответ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бесплатно перевожу ответы с комментов в секцию ответов :

30K символов. [Пруф](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PWkD.jpg)

Нет стеснению! Обращайтесь.